# Zend_Http_Client cURL authorization example

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, curl, authorization

I need to create authorization script. Cookies must be saved and used later to access the page without authorization. Can anyone give me work example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to do an initial request to get the cookies from the server. In the response, you will save the cookies the server sends in the response header `Set-Cookie`. Where you store them is up to you. I just added them to a session.

```
    $uri    = 'http://example.com';
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $client->setUri($uri);
    $client->setAdapter('Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl');
    $adapter = $client->getAdapter();
    $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    /** First Request to get required cookies **/
    $response = $client->request();

    /** Get response cookie strings and store them (session, db, file, etc) **/
    $cookies  = (array) $response->getHeader('Set-cookie');
    $session  = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    $session->storedCookies = $cookies;
```

Now that you have the cookies stored, on your next request you can add them to the request.

```
    /** Start new Zend_Http_Client instance **/
    $uri      = 'http://example.com';
    $client   = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $client->setUri($uri);
    $client->setAdapter('Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl');
    $adapter  = $client->getAdapter();
    /** This setCurlOption is optional **/
    $adapter->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    $cookies = $session->storedCookies;
    /** Add Stored Cookie strings to Zend_Http_Client instance **/ 
    foreach ($cookies as $cookieStr) {
        $client->setCookie(Zend_Http_Cookie::fromString($cookieStr, $uri));
    }

    /** Perform request using stored cookies **/
    $response = $client->request();
```

If you have questions or need me to elaborate on anything, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its just what I seek.
As I know curl can hold persistent connection and use it for several requests in queue. How can this be done with Zend?